# Laravel $request->filled() method throws error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, request

I am trying to check if value is present on the request or not using filled function in laravel ! But Laravel throws BadMethodCallException.
Preview of what I got in response
[image]
Is this method deprecated ?? or any similar approach to check if request parameter is empty in laravel ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `filled` method on `Illuminate\Http\Request` in Laravel >= 5.5

Would need to know what version you are using to look into it more.

Comment: Oh ! Its my fault ! I was referring Laravel 5.5 docs :( :( . Actually I was using Latavel 5.3 ! Thanks for the quick reply ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `has()` method as well:

```
if ($request->has('name')) {
    // code here
}
```